# ReactJS scroll offset incorrect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How could I fix scroll position on country list when there is sticky positioned element on top of long item list. I have created a sandbox to show the problem (below post).

Use case: If I click on country "Kenya", page scrolls in to "red zone" (footer text). Sadly, cannot make it scroll up to "green zone", where the country content is what ever country is clicked. It works fine for the countries starting with "A" letter (sort of).. scroll position is not below sticky element.

https://codesandbox.io/s/j69bwo?file=/src/App.js

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The countries list height when collapsed will force the page to scroll to the bottom.

One solution is using `scrollIntoView` method to scroll to the `wrapper` element after choosing a country.

```
  const wrapperRef = useRef();

  const showCountry = (item) => {
    setView({ list: false, item: true });
    setItem(item);
    wrapperRef.current.scrollIntoView();
  };

  // code...
  <div className="wrapper" ref={wrapperRef}>
```

[image: Edit scroll-to-list-top (forked)]